# TwoD Physics Addon won't Activate in Blender 2.93

Tags: python, add-on, physics, 2d

I installed the addon successfully but when I tried activating the TwoD Physics Addon I was met by a series of errors as shown below. I don't really have much knowledge of Python Programming so I can't figure out what the problem is. I'm currently using Blender 2.93

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Installed Windows Programs\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
    mod = __import__(module_name)
  File "C:\Users\ERISOL\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\gscatter\t3dn.py", line 615, in _packer_import
    return _orig_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\ERISOL\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\twod-physics\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    import pymunk
  File "C:\Users\ERISOL\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\gscatter\t3dn.py", line 615, in _packer_import
    return _orig_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\ERISOL\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\twod-physics\modules\pymunk\__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import _chipmunk_cffi
  File "C:\Users\ERISOL\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\gscatter\t3dn.py", line 615, in _packer_import
    return _orig_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\ERISOL\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\twod-physics\modules\pymunk\_chipmunk_cffi.py", line 3, in <module>
    from pymunk._chipmunk_cffi_abi import ffi, lib, lib_path
  File "C:\Users\ERISOL\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\gscatter\t3dn.py", line 615, in _packer_import
    return _orig_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "C:\Users\ERISOL\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\twod-physics\modules\pymunk\_chipmunk_cffi_abi.py", line 1466, in <module>
    ffi = FFI()
  File "C:\Users\ERISOL\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\twod-physics\modules\cffi\api.py", line 48, in __init__
    import _cffi_backend as backend
  File "C:\Users\ERISOL\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\gscatter\t3dn.py", line 615, in _packer_import
    return _orig_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_cffi_backend'
```

Here's a link to the latest version of the addon
[TwoDPhysics Addon for 2d Rigid Body Physics](https://theunnecessarythings.gumroad.com/l/BCCzHR?recommended_by=library).

Thank you in advance. Apologies if I posted the question in the wrong section.

Answer (score 0):

ok, i just tried it out, works pretty nice...

Just setup your rigid bodies, and restrict location movements like this:

[image]

1. lock location y
2. lock rotation x and z

Run the simulation.

result:

[image]